# Qt Creator and SFML - No Window Appearing

Tags: c++, qt, sfml

I've been trying to set up SFML with QT Creator but I've been running into issues. The application runs **without any errors**, but no window will appear. It exits with **code 0** and displays a console window with "Press  to close this window...". Nothing else happens. Does anyone know what might be missing/wrong?

Thanks.

---

### .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

INCLUDEPATH += C:/SFML-2.0/include

LIBS += C:/SFML-2.0/lib/libsfml-system.a \
    C:/SFML-2.0/lib/libsfml-window.a \
    C:/SFML-2.0/lib/libsfml-graphics.a \
    C:/SFML-2.0/lib/libsfml-audio.a \
    C:/SFML-2.0/lib/libsfml-network.a

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

### main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(320, 480), "My window");
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Additional Information

- Windows 7
- Qt 4.8.1 for Desktop - MinGW (Qt SDK)
- SFML 2.0 (GCC 4.7 MinGW (DW2) - 32bit)
- copied SFML lib files to C:\Windows\SYSWOW64
- removing the "CONFIG += console" does not help
- adding "CONFIG -= gui" does not help

Comment: You should add a `window.display();` in your main loop. Does it fix your issue ?

BTW, QT is QuickTime. Qt is the correct spelling.

Comment: `window.display()` either inside the main loop or outside the main loop didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking "run in a terminal" option in projects/run settings.

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Add the DLL files of the SFML inside your project folder (NOT in the debug/release folder).

Hope this helps.